# Getting `id` of newly created record after `save()`

Tags: fat-free-framework

As per **[`save` Cursor Method documentation](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.8/cursor#save)**

> This method saves data to the database. The Cursor class automatically determines if the record should be updated or inserted as a new entry, based on the return value of dry.

In case a new record is created how do I retrieve its auto-increment primary key `id` (this is how my tables are defined) ?

I'm used to look for the mapper instance propery `_id` but this is undocumented (afaik).

I suppose I can set up an `afterinsert()` event handler but I was looking for a more straightforward approach. Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy and straighforward:

after a `save()` on a "dry" record (a new record has been created) autoincrement primary keys are updated on the mapper object, so in my case:

```php
$mapper->save();
$id = $mapper->id;
```